# Clear and replace value which are in array by angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ngfor

I want to calculate the distance between two persons and write them on web page. While I am writing value on html, code is being pushed more than one but I don't want it like this. I want to replace the new one

```
this.db.list("Users/subscribed/" + user.uid + "/members").snapshotChanges().subscribe(items => {
          items.forEach(item => {
            let container = {
              lat: 0,
              lng: 0,
              distance: "0",
            }
            let child = item.payload.child("locations")
            child.forEach(element => {
              if (element.key === "lat") {
                container.lat = element.toJSON() as number
              }
              else if (element.key == "lng") {
                container.lng = element.toJSON() as number
              }
            })
            this.fbGetLoc(user.uid).then(result => {
              this.lat = result.val()

              this.fbGetLoc2(user.uid).then(result2 => {
                this.lng = result2.val()
              })
            }).then(() => {

                container.distance = this.calculate(this.lat, this.lng, container.lat, container.lng) as any    

            })
            this.MemberLocation.push(container)

          })
        })


         <div class="list-group ; text-center " *ngFor="let distance of MemberLocation">                   
                  <a class="list-group-item pt-5">         
                      <strong>Tahmini Uzaklık: {{distance.distance}} km 
                    </strong>           
                  </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand the logic in the above code by putting `MemberLocation` inside a forEach statement, which would eventually give you a new value upon iteration. But, I think you should use a variable instead of an array for this usecase like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

interface Location {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  distance: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  MemberLocation: Location;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._calculateDistance();
  }

  private _calculateDistance() {
    this.db.list("Users/subscribed/" + user.uid + "/members").snapshotChanges().subscribe(items => {
      items.forEach(item => {
        // Your calculation logic here

        // You can set the data on this location field
        this.MemberLocation = container;
      });
    });
  }

}
```

and in your html you could do this

```html
<div class="list-group text-center">                   
    <a class="list-group-item pt-5" *ngIf="MemberLocation">         
        <strong>Tahmini Uzaklık: {{MemberLocation?.distance}} km</strong>           
    </a>
</div>
```